# Postgress how to AUTOMATICALLY left outter join to tables with reference integrity constraints?

Tags: postgresql

Has anyone written PG_SQL or such method that would generate left outer join queries from reference constraint data only.

Generating these queries, when you need to always takes time, and for most cases this highly mechanical work.

Lets say we have tables ( just as an example to make the question more concrete ).

```
create table aaa ( id bigint, name varchar);
create table aaa_option( id bigint,aaa_id bigint, name varchar, value varchar);
create table aaa_sub_option( id bigint,option_id bigint, name varchar, value varchar);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX on aaa(id) ;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON aaa_sub_option(id) ;

ALTER TABLE aaa_option ADD CONSTRAINT aaa_const FOREIGN KEY (aaa_id) REFERENCES aaa(id);
ALTER TABLE aaa_sub_option ADD CONSTRAINT aaa_sub_const FOREIGN KEY (option_id) REFERENCES aaa_sub_option(id);
```

I am looking for a function like:

```
rquery('aaa',1);
```

would give me

```
select aaa.id as aaa_X_id, aaa.name as aaa_X_name from aaa;
```

```
rquery(aaa,2)
```

would give me:

```
select aaa.id as aaa_X_id, aaa.name as aaa_X_name,
    X1.id as aaa_option_X_id, X1.aaa_id as aaa_option_X_aaa_id, X1.name as aaa_option_X_name,X1.value as aaa_option_X_value from aaa
  left outer join aaa_option as X1 on aaa.id=X1.aaa_id;
```

rquery(aaa,3)

would give me:

... to be writen ...

Comment: There could be several such constraints. I think a magic automatism like that can do as much harm as it can do good

Comment: I do know this. Object relational mappers for most things do this for programming, I am looking a ad hoc tool for looking at data.

The point is not to waste hours for generating trivial queries, but minutes to customise "stupid tool output" to do what you need.

Comment: If you're just looking to avoid repetitive work writing queries, perhaps a [VIEW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) is what you're looking for. You would have to design each view yourself, but only once. Then you could query the view as many times as you like.  I think it would be harmful to automate this, because it would tend to suck in _all_ tables that are referenced, whether you need them or not (in other words, you'd turn your queries into ones generated by Hibernate).

Comment: I don't get what `1`, `2` or `3` would mean in those  `rquery` calls

Comment: Afaik pgadmin4 can auto-complete `JOIN` conditions based on foreign key constraints

Comment: ```auto-complete JOIN conditions based on foreign key constraints```

I was not aware of this !

Comment: @Bergi `1`, `2` and `3` are depth, I think. Assuming `aaa` is *top level*, `rquery('aaa',1);` returns only that. `aaa_option` being a child suggests `rquery('aaa',2);` fetches that, together with parent `aaa`. `3` would fetch `aaa_sub_option`, its parent `aaa_option`, and its parent `aaa`. PGAdmin auto-completion is there, but it's not very good: in this case the first join autocompletes nicely, [nothing after that does](https://imgur.com/a/VPIAZ37). But I think you struck gold with the suggestion of IDE auto-complete in general

Answer (score 0):

The use case sounds a bit like what [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) is for. In PostgreSQL, you can store and operate on graphs using [`pgrouting`](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_connectedComponents.html) or [Apache AGE](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/clauses/match.html) (your `rquery` resembles [variable-length edge query](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/clauses/match.html#introduction)), but they don't necessarily structure the graph data the way you do.

You can try those out, or you can even do something like that in vanilla PostgreSQL with a self-referencing table and a [recursive query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE) on that: replace the 3 tables with a single one: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0ZGTGoOu)

```
create table aaa_option (
    id bigint generated by default as identity primary key, 
    aaa_parent_id bigint references aaa_option(id),
    name varchar,
    value text);
create index on aaa_option(aaa_parent_id);
insert into aaa_option values
(1,null,'this is a parent, a top-level aaa'              ,null),
(2,1   ,'this is a child, an "aaa_option"'               ,100),
(3,2   ,'this is a child of a child, an "aaa_sub_option"',101);
```

And then your `rquery(N)` is this:

```
prepare rquery(int,text) as 
with recursive cte as (
   select id, 
       aaa_parent_id,
       name,
       value
   from aaa_option a where aaa_parent_id is null
   union all 
   select aaa.id, 
       aaa.aaa_parent_id,
       aaa.name,
       aaa.value
   from cte inner join aaa_option aaa on (aaa.aaa_parent_id=cte.id)
   where not is_cycle 
   )cycle id set is_cycle using path
select * from cte 
where case $2 when 'eq'  then array_length(path,1) =  $1
              when 'geq' then array_length(path,1) >= $1
              when 'leq' then array_length(path,1) <= $1
              when 'lt'  then array_length(path,1) <  $1
              when 'gt'  then array_length(path,1) >  $1 
              when 'neq' then array_length(path,1) <> $1 
              else            true 
       end;
```

```
execute rquery(3,'leq');
```

| id | aaa_parent_id | name | value | is_cycle | path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | this is a parent, a top-level aaa | *null* | f | {(1)} |
| 2 | 1 | this is a child, an "aaa_option" | 100 | f | {(1),(2)} |
| 3 | 2 | this is a child of a child, an "aaa_sub_option" | 101 | f | {(1),(2),(3)} |

To have the three structures hold different fields on top of the shared hierarchy, you [*could*](https://dbfiddle.uk/1ECadfju) use [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-inheritance.html):

```
create table aaa (
    id bigint generated by default as identity primary key,
    aaa_parent_id bigint references aaa(id), 
    name text);
create table aaa_option (
    value text) inherits (aaa);
create table aaa_sub_option () inherits (aaa_option);
```

Comment: Recursive queries work for recursive tables, not exactly what I am looking for.

... or actually the metadata is a recursive table that has what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of assumed no such thing has been done, but wanted to check no-one disagrees on this.

I think I would probably some time to get this done.

```
     SELECT con.conname,con.contype,rel.relname as relname,UNNEST(conkey) as conkey_ ,rel2.relname,UNNEST(confkey) as confkey_,
            attr.attname,attr.atttypid,attr.attnum,attr2.attname,attr2.atttypid,attr2.attnum
       FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint con
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class rel
                       ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class rel2
                       ON rel2.oid = con.confrelid                     
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp
                       ON nsp.oid = connamespace
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attribute attr
                       ON rel.oid=attr.attrelid 
            INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attribute attr2
                       ON rel2.oid=attr2.attrelid                      
       WHERE  contype='f' -- foreign key           
       AND  attr.attnum = ANY ( conkey)
       AND  attr2.attnum = ANY ( confkey)
        ;
```

Will get neat info

```
     conname    | contype |    relname     | conkey_ |    relname     | confkey_ |  attname  | atttypid | attnum | attname | atttypid | attnum
---------------+---------+----------------+---------+----------------+----------+-----------+----------+--------+---------+----------+--------
 aaa_const     | f       | aaa_option     |       2 | aaa            |        1 | aaa_id    |       20 |      2 | id      |       20 |      1
 aaa_sub_const | f       | aaa_sub_option |       2 | aaa_sub_option |        1 | option_id |       20 |      2 | id      |       20 |      1
(2 rows)
```

It looks like all the information I need is there, not that I doubled it would not be accessible.

I would only need to write some PG_PSQL or java to process it into a query generation.

... perhaps I could use recursive querying here.